# I cannot access SO using the default Win XP account

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I can access SO with different XP accounts, but I cannot access it with the default account. My browser shows nothing. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What browser? Do you accept cookies?

Comment: Shows nothing? The void? Screenshots? Any? Circles? Awesome ones, not the lame ones...

Comment: Man, asked 47 minutes ago and nobody has pulled out the old chestnut yet?  Fine, I'll do it: stop using Windows XP.

Comment: @John Smithers, when you edit a Q to fix the spelling then please don't add your own. :-) resovle? What's resovle? ;-)

Comment: Rhymes with waffle.

Comment: @Workshop Alex: Man, I missde teh corrcet positoin yb oen lettre. Whats' yoru probelm?

Comment: @random: I will accept cookies. What kind are you making for us?

Comment: These cookies come from the easy-bake **Opera** oven. Enjoy your afternoon delight.

Comment: What do you see if you look at the page source? Also, have you tried emptying you browser cache completely?

Answer (score 1):

Define "could not access"? My first guess would be that your proxy server (wininet) is not configured (if needed), or that your browser's settings (on that account) has the site filtered or crippled (cookies, script, etc).

Comment: I could not access means, the site shows nothing. Even the logo of stackoverflow loads near url box,but it does not displays any page.I use firefox. In all other browser i have same problem..help me in this..Now I am using another account
I can access all other websites.